# How to prove correctness using loop invariant for this question can anyone help me understand this?

Tags: algorithm

function multiply(y, z)
// comment Return yz, where y, z  ∈IN

```
x := 0;
while z > 0 do
if z mod 2 = 1
  then x := x + y;
  y := 2y;
  z := z/2 ;
return(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I give just some hints and leave the actual proofs for you. A useful invariant in this case is `product = x + y * z`. You prove three things:

1. it is true at the beginning of the loop
2. it stays true for each iteration
3. at the end of the loop you have additionally `z = 0` and therefore `product = x`